# Firebase run payments with stripe extension

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am using the Run Payments with Stripe extension and I have a couple webhooks set up including checkout.session.completed and I was wondering how I could post the job object to Firestore only after successful payment?

My .ts code:

```
  const docRef = await db
                .collection('users')
                .doc(uid)
                .collection('checkout_sessions')
                .add({
                  automatic_tax: true, // Automatically calculate tax based on the customer's address
                  tax_id_collection: true, // Collect the customer's tax ID (important for B2B transactions)
                  payment_method_types: ["card"],
                  mode: 'subscription',
                  line_items: [
                    {
                      price: this.paymentPlan.stripePriceId,
                      quantity: 1,
                      description: jobData.jobLevel + ' ' + jobData.jobTitle,
                    },
                  ],
                  allow_promotion_codes: true,
                  success_url: 'http://localhost:4200/success',
                  cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4200/success',
                  metadata: {
                    payId: payId
                  }
                });
              // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension

              docRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
                const { error, url } = snap.data() as any;;
                if (error) {
                  // Show an error to your customer and
                  // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
                  alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
                }
                if (url) {
                  // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, let's redirect.
                  window.location.assign(url);
                }
                this.loading = false;

              });

              
              this.db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('jobs').add(job).then(() => {
                console.log('Job posted successfully!');
              }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Error posting job:', error);
              });
```

Would I need to write my own Firebase functions to listen to the webhook and post a job that way?

Thank you!

Comment: "Would I need to write my own Firebase functions to listen to the webhook" => Yes, see [Call functions via HTTP requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need a Firebase function that listens to the webhook event `payment_intent.success`[1] and `checkout.session.completed`[2]. You can follow this sample[3]. Then make a call to firestore in order to create a record[4]

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed

[3] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L676

[4] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/055d467b3aa9441dae372904818847fb222ba57d/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L634